# Two-way binding for select Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Angular2, in my ts, I have a control group, how can I have the two-way binding for the select in my html using ngFormControl?

form.component.ts

```
this._reportGeneratingForm = fb.group({
 ......

  selectedGroup: ['']
})
```

form.component.html

```
  <select class="form-control" ????>
      <option>Day</option>
      <option>Hour</option>
      <option>week</option>
      <option>Month</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```ts
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="someProperty">
  <option>Day</option>
  <option>Hour</option>
  <option>week</option>
  <option>Month</option>
</select>
```

where `someProperty` is a property on the components class that holds the  value or

```ts
<select class="form-control" [ngFormControl]="selectControl">
  <option>Day</option>
  <option>Hour</option>
  <option>week</option>
  <option>Month</option>
</select>
```

This only works properly on all browsers if you have a recent Angular2 version (>= beta.16)

Comment: can I use ngFormControl?

Comment: Yes, I tried ngFormControl. It is working. For my case, I may not need a data model

Comment: selected="selected" is not working, override by the data-binding

Comment: I Plunker to see what you actually trying to accomplish and to be able to reproduce and debug the issue would be helpful. The `New` button in Plunker provides a Angular2 rx.1 template.

Comment: Tks Gunter, it is working now             <select class="form-control" id="groupingBySelect" [ngFormControl]="_reportGeneratingForm.controls['grouping']">
              <option selected="selected">Day</option>
              <option>Hour</option>
              <option>week</option>
              <option>Month</option>
            </select>

Comment: just to update that selected attribute is not working in this approach, you have to set the grouping value in ts

Answer (score 0):

In this example selected atribute is not working !
But in ts file

- For the ngModel : You can write as `someProperty = Day`
- For the ngFormControl: You can also write as `selectControl.value= Day`

It will works fine.