# How to show and hide the calendar based on condition in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if, ng-show, angularjs-ng-if

I have an angular application in that I need to show the caledar based selected dropdown list.

**.component.ts**

```
OptionList: LookupActionCode[]=[];
public setList(actionType: any):void{
  this.anotherOptionList = [];
   if(actionType == dataConstant.calendar){
  this.List.push(
       {
          
          Name: dataConstant.calendar
       },
      {
       Name: dataConstant.showCalendar
      },
 {
  Name: dataConstant.hideCalendar
       },
   )}

 switch(actionType){
    case dataConstant.memberdata:
      this.OptionList = this.memberDataCodes;
      break;
      case dataConstant.referral:
        this.OptionList= this.referralCodes;
      break;
     
      case dataConstant.Calendar:
        this.OptionList = this.List;
        break;
     }
```

**.component.html**

```
//first dropdown
<label for="OptionList" class="cpp-required"> <b>Action</b></label>
 <select id=action class="form-control"  required  (change) ="setList($event.target.value)">
               <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
             <option [value] = "dataConstant.referral">{{dataConstant.referral}}</option>
 <option [value] = "dataConstant.memberdata">{{dataConstant.memberdata}}</option>
 <option [value] = "dataConstant.calendar">{{dataConstant.calendar}}</option>
             </select>    
//second dropdown


<label> <b>Action</b></label>
 <select id=action class="form-control"  required>
               <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
               <option *ngFor="let option of OptionList" [value] ="option">{{option.Name}} </option>
             </select>   

<div >
 <angular2-fullcalendar [options]="Options" id="Calendars"></angular2-fullcalendar>
        </div>
```

So my requirement is when we select the dataConstant.calendar from the firstdropdown category list,
It will show the releted lists in Action dropdown second list(Implemented) from the seconfd dropdown if I select the dataConstant.showCalendar option I need to show the calendar

I have tried <div *ngIf =" OptionList.Name===dataConstant.showCalendar">But not working
Can anyone helpme on this

Answer (score 0):

You could two-way bind what is current selected value of `select` and using `*ngIf` if `selectedOption` is `dataConstant.showCalendar` we show calendar. Because this is regular HTML select we must use `[(ngModel)]`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37109241/15439733

```html
<select id="action" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
   <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
   <option *ngFor="let option of OptionList" [value] ="option">{{option.Name}} </option>
</select> 

<div *ngIf="selectedOption.Name === 'dataConstant.showCalendar'">
   <angular2-fullcalendar [options]="Options" id="Calendars"></angular2-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

This part you have to look over yourself so that the if check for `===` operator would match your case. I don't quite understand what exactly must match. Hope you get the general idea of it.

`*ngIf="selectedOption.Name === 'dataConstant.showCalendar'"`

---

PS. In javascript we name variables and properties in camelCase. `OptionList` -> `optionList`, `Name` -> `name`. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp

Comment: Thanks@ Joosep.P , I need to match the dataConstant.showCalendar from optionList will be same is dadaConstant.showCalendar then Only i need to show the calendar,could you help me on this